Is it safe to expose a limited SQL query service endpoint?
We want to create a read-only query API endpoint, allowing clients to access their data by sending raw SQL strings. We would parse the queries as AST and validate them against our restricted schema, essentially permitting only simplified Select statements, no multiple queries/subqueries etc. What security issues could arise from this?
Edit: I'd like to clarify that the intention isn't to allow a raw SQL access but to control it at the language-level, essentially being selective at which features are turned on. Here is a simple demo I've prepped to explain the idea: https://sql-api-demo.vercel.app. Source code here.

If I am being honest, that looks like a bad idea to me but to know how bad, could you please share more information? Things like whether you will be storing e.g. personal data, whether client A and client B must be restricted from seeing each other's record, and if yes, how you will separate data, etc...

@Atmo Thanks for the comment. Each client will have a Postgres database user with minimum privileges to access specific tables. We would use Row-Level Security, so only records for the authoring users will be visible. Other than that, records from clients will share the same table.

Assuming you have a table with 20 available rows and you cross join it with itself 10 times you'll be asking the server to produce 10,240,000,000,000 rows. That'll consume a fair few resources, and is just a simple select statement.

Grant no access whatsover to the tables. Only grant access to a (few) safe stored procedures, returning data in a controlled way.

@Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks! I agree, DoS and metering would be an issue, but that is so with graphql or odata.

@Kazlauskis no, it's definitely not the same. Both GraphQL and OData come with everything disabled. The backend developer can control which features are allowed, set limit and, given the design of both, use techniques that fit the web environment. The only schema allowed is the one specified by the backend developer as the model, exposed as metadata

"..by sending raw SQL strings..." - NO. IT'S NOT SAFE. DO NOT DO IT. Create an API instead with a rate limiter.

I've clarified my question. The intention is to be selective about which SQL 'features' we support.

What you are doing is called "code injection" and is one of the OWASP top 10 security risks. Never never do this. If you want to expose "selective features" then write those features in the server and allow the client to call "feature #1" or "feature #2" with no SQL and no injection of anything.

Here is an interesting article that supports this idea as well. https://valentin.willscher.de/posts/sql-api

Emphatically, no.
SQL is just too powerful. Even if you parse the query and think you have covered all the bases, a smart attacker will find a statement that avoids your defenses and brings your database down (or worse).

@laurenz-albe  Thanks for your input. I've clarified my original question. The idea is to dumb down the SQL, so it's not "too powerful".

Right. But I would argue that either the dumbed-down SQL is too dumb to be useful, or too dangerous. For example, if I am allowed to join, I can easily write a query that exhausts the server's resources.

This basic demo example I provided, which enables selecting fields, filtering, and pagination, addresses most of the typical read-only API requirements. For joins we can detect circular references and control the number of joins at the AST level too.
